# Formatting multiple ranges in VBA Excel with a single line code

Tags: vba, excel, syntax, format

How does one formatting multiple ranges of cells number, alignment, font, border, fill, protection, etc in VBA Excel with a single line code? For instance, I have the following code

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 15
    .Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 15
    .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 15
    .Range("A:C").Font.Color = vbRed
    .Range("G:G").Font.Color = vbRed
End With
```

Could I do instead something like (pseudo-code):

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Columns("A", "C", "G").ColumnWidth = 15
    .Range("A:C", "G:G").Font.Color = vbRed
End With
```

I thought something like `.Columns(Array("A", "C", "G")).ColumnWidth = 15` would work, but an error occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try:
`.Range("A:A, C:C, G:G").ColumnWidth = 15`
and
`.Range("A:C, G:G").Font.Color = vbRed`

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thanks. (+1)

Comment: You are very welcome. Please mark as the answer :) Thank you

Comment: I have to wait for a couple of minutes before doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of ranges,

```
dim rng as Excel.Range
set rng=array(range("C:C"),range("E:E"),range("G:G"))
```

or use a function, something like, which will still be valid if using array.

```
public function CustomFormat(rng as excel.range) 

rng.ColumnWidth = 15
rng.interior.color=vbRed    

end function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even use `Union` as:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("C"), .Columns("G")).ColumnWidth = 15
    Union(.Columns("A:C"), .Columns("G")).Font.Color = vbRed
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could even a named range to do this, it's up to you:)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13099096)

Comment: It does, he could create a named range of his columns, A, C & G, no critique at all, and an answer.